# How to create an input where display and model value differ?

Tags: angular, directive

I'm trying to create an input that displays a time format but holds a value in minutes. For instance: 1:30 holds a value of 90.

My first option was to use a directive.
Now if I change the value in the input to 75 the value displayed should be 1:15.
I prefer not to use the @Output and EventEmitter and set up a method to change my value.

Component:

```
public value = 90;
```

View:

```
<p><input [(appTimespan)]="value"></p>
<p>Value: {{ value }}</p>
```

Directive (snip):

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appTimespan]'})
export class TimespanDirective {
    @Input( 'appTimespan' ) value: string;
    // @Output( 'out' ) update = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        // just to indicate the directive is applied
        element.nativeElement.style.backroundColor = 'yellow';
    }

    @HostListener('change') onChange() {
        // skip the code for calculations and formatting
        this.value = 75;
        this.element.nativeElement.value = '1:15';
        // this.update.emit(75);
    }
}
```

The (display)value of my input is set to '1:15', great...
But the value displayed in the view still shows my initial value 90 where I expect it to be 75.

Comment: you want to display the formatted time in input itself or in a seperate div? like in: `<p>Value: {{ value }}</p>` How is the user going to change values like: `1:15, 1,16, etc` or `90,91,etc` ?

Comment: If its only w.r.t to display, creating a simple pipe to display computed value should work.

Comment: I need the value in the component. I'm displaying just to debug.
A user can enter values like '0:45', '30' or even '0.25'. Calculations are not the problem. 
The user input should be stored in the component field value as a number and the timeformat should be the "value" of the input.

Answer (score 1):

I like use @HotListener blur and focus see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xahrbm?file=src/app/test.pipe.ts)

In blur, you transform the value of the htmlElement. In Focus parse the value. Be carefully, you must use ngOnInit to show the correct value at first time. If we are using the directive in a input [(ngModel)] we must use a setTimeOut -else, the first time not show the correct value-

```
export class TestPipe  implements OnInit {

  private el: any;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus() {
    this.el.value = this.parse(this.el.value); 
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = this.transform(value);
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.el.value = this.transform(this.el.value);
    })

  }
  transform(value:any)
  {
      let minutes=+value;
      let hour=Math.floor(minutes/60);
      let rest=minutes%60;
      return hour+":"+('00'+rest).slice(-2);
  }
  parse(value:any)
  {
    let hours=value.split(":");
    return ''+((+hours[0])*60+(+hours[1]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx. I had an AngularJS solution quite like this. There I used the formatters and parsers of the ngmodel in a directive. 
I'm searching for a way to return the model value as a number and have display value in the input as a time string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe to show minutes to hours format.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fr2oqw)

Component:

```
public value: number = 90;
```

View:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value" />
<p>Value: {{ value | toTime }}</p>
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'toTime'})
export class ToTime implements PipeTransform {

  convertMinsToHrsMins(minutes) {
    let h:any = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    let m:any = minutes % 60;
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    return h + ':' + m;
  }

  transform(value: number): string {
    return this.convertMinsToHrsMins(value);
  }
}
```

**Edit**
You can use same pipe in component for getting hours

```
submit(){
  console.log(this.toTime.transform(this.value))
}
```

Comment: Tnx, but the formatting is NOT the issue. I need the value in the component.

Comment: @Elko This is where pipes are for. Pipe are mainly uses to transform a value in the view and not in the component

Comment: @Elko You can use same pipe in component like `this.toTime.transform(this.value)`. I updated stackblitz demo please check.

Comment: Tnx. Again, calculations and formatting is not the issue. Goal is to transform a regular text-input to a timespan-input, where the value displayed in the input (after change) is time-format, and the model value is in minutes (number).

Comment: So user can minutes or time in input at same time input should convert to time and show time in same input but model should contain minutes value. This is what you want ?

Comment: @Javascript Hupp Technologies
Yes! Exacty. The model value in minutes and the input.value is a string.

Comment: @Elko I tried to achieve and i think using same ngModel it's not possible. On change of model you should update other model and show it on other side either play with css to show two value inside input like i did in [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fr2oqw)

Comment: This answer is kind of useless.  Instead of offering a way to format input values, it just demonstrates how pipes work on interpolated text.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use keyUp event, and calculate the time every time you add/delete a number

Html:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value"  (keyup)="changeDisplayValue()" />
<p>Value: {{ displayValue }}</p>
```

TS:

```
 export class AppComponent  {
 public value: number = 90;  
 displayValue: any;

constructor(){
 this.displayValue = this.convertTime(this.value);
}

changeDisplayValue(){
  this.displayValue = this.convertTime(this.value);
}

convertTime(minutesValue) {
  let h = Math.floor(minutesValue / 60);
  let m = minutesValue % 60;  
  return (h < 10 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m);
}
}
```

This way you dont need any extra code, and the value updates the moment you change it.

Comment: Tnx for your input but.... I actually need a (easily reusable) directive/component. This way one gets a lot of repetitive code.